# highlight cell based on events

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to highlight the cells based on the events? For example, an event for July 5th to July 9th, I would like the cell to be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the property  "className"  for these specific events

Comment: No, className only changes the class of the event element, not the table cell under it.